# stm32 lwip - unable to respond to ping

Tags: stm32, lwip

I am trying to configure the minimum I can to get my Nucleo-F429ZI to respond to a ping

Using CubeMX, I enable ethernet in MII mode and assign a unique MAC address.

In Middleware I enable LwIP (no RTOS, no DHCP) I set an IP of 192.168.1.55, 255.255.255.0, 192.168.1.1.

I enable ICMP, UDP and TCP.

I build in TrueStudio and run, but no response to a ping from my linux box on the same network.

In main.c I see 
MX_LWIP_Init();  which call lwip_init() with the address mask and gw I configured.

In lwip.c 
I see my IP, mask and gw initialized correctly followed by lwip_init();

I try to ping from my linux box (same network) but get "host not found"

What am I missing???

Answer (score 2):

in Nucleo-F429ZI the Ethernet physical chips is LAN8742A-CZ-TR that you should configure Ethernet media (your micro mac) in RMII  mode, FOR MII interface you need RXD[3:0] and TXD[3:0] between your media level and physical level , but if you look at LAN8742A-CZ-TR datasheet or  Nucleo-F429ZI  schematic you found that between your physical and media you just  have  RXD[1:0] and TXD[1:0] pins that is RMII standard interface

your problem can occur according several reasons, 
check your media config
check connection and look at links led on your eth connector
check auto negotiation process between your Linux box and phy

Answer (score 0):

CubeMX default RMII pinout and Nucleo-F429ZI pinouts are different. You must change the following pins for achieving communication via ethernet.

```
PB11 -> PG11 (RMII_TX_EN)
PB12 -> PG13 (RMII_TX_D1)
```

Also, PHY address is should set to 0 in ETH settings.